# How to make arduino go in two direction using h-bridge?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am tring to build a line follower robot, i have an h-bridge and arduino to control the direction and speed.

I burnt this code to my arduino board, but the robot just go forward and never go on the oppsite direction:

```
int enA = 10;
int in1 = 9;
int in2 = 8;
// motor two
int enB = 5;
int in3 = 7;
int in4 = 6;


void setup()
{
 pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
}

void demoOne()
{
 digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
 analogWrite(enA, 200);
 // turn on motor B
 digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
 // set speed to 200 out of possible range 0~255
 analogWrite(enB, 200);
 delay(2000);
 // now change motor directions
 digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
 digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
 delay(2000);
 // now turn off motors
 digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
 digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
}
void loop()
{
 demoOne();
 delay(1000);
 demoTwo();
 delay(1000);
}
```

How to adjust the code to make it go for both directions?

UPDATE:
I am using h bridge l298n and four dc motors "2 right and 2 left", powering it with two 9v batteries and powering the arduino uno with 5v which i get from the h bridge based on this article:
https://hackerstore.nl/PDFs/Tutorial298.pdf

enA, in1, and in2 for the two right motors

enB, in3, and in4 for the two left motors

Comment: Your code looks fine. Which H-Brigde driver are you using? Take in account that some H bridge shields use a single pin for direction instead of two.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki It's still not workin. I am using h bridge l298n and four dc motors "2 right and 2 left", powering it with two 9v batteries and powering the arduino uno with 5v which i get from the h bridge based on this article:
https://hackerstore.nl/PDFs/Tutorial298.pdf

enA, in1, and in2 for the two right motors
enB, in3, and in4 for the two left motors

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly fine, make sure your hardware is working properly and that everything is connected properly, also make sure that you are not using the 5V from your Arduino to power the motors since the small voltage regulator on the Arduino board is not capable of handling high currents such as 500mA (Unless you replace it with a bigger regulator and give it a big heatsink), if you are powering the arduino and motors from USB make sure your USB port can handle the power required by the two motors, oh and make sure pins 10 and 5 are PWM pins

Also using a dedicated motor library may help to simplify your code, I wrote you one here:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define enA 10
#define enB 5
#define i1 8
#define i2 9
#define i3 6
#define i4 7

void initMotors(){
    pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(i1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(i2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(i3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(i4, OUTPUT);
}
void motor1Stop(){
    digitalWrite(i1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(i2, LOW);
}
void motor2Stop(){
    digitalWrite(i3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(i4, LOW);
}
void motorsEnabled(bool en){
    digitalWrite(enA, en);
    digitalWrite(enB, en);
}
void enableMotors(){
    motorsEnabled(HIGH);
}
void motor1Forward(){
    digitalWrite(i1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(i2, LOW);
}
void motor1Backward(){
    digitalWrite(i1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(i2, HIGH);
}
void motor2Forward(){
    digitalWrite(i3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(i4, HIGH);
}
void motor2Backward(){
    digitalWrite(i3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(i4, LOW);
}
```

To include this just make a new tab and name it whatever you want (as long as there are no spaces and it ends in .h), then add `#include "name.h"` to the beginning of your code, this will help you to reduce future bugs

For speed control you can add this:

```
void setMotorSpeeds(int motor1, int motor2){
    analogWrite(enA, motor1);
    analogWrite(enB, motor2);
}
```

Comment: It's still not workin. I am using h bridge l298n and four dc motors "2 right and 2 left", powering it with two 9v batteries and powering the arduino uno with 5v which i get from the h bridge based on this article:
https://hackerstore.nl/PDFs/Tutorial298.pdf

enA, in1, and in2 for the two right motors
enB, in3, and in4 for the two left motors

Comment: You're doing it all right, If you can try it with another H-Bridge because you could have a bad h-bridge, and replace the jumpers connecting as well since the flexible jumper wires can easily go bad

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, so you will need to identify the problem by "divide and conquer"

Connect a single motor to each channel, and forget the arduino part for now.

Connect the L298 power supply. If you read the instructions you will see that you can use the integrated 5V power regulator, or you can supply an external 5V. If using a different power supply for 5V and Motors **make sure you connect both GND together** otherwise it won't work.

Make sure you have the driver properly connected to power supply, take two cables and use them to connect in1 to GND, in2 to 5V and enA to 5V (without the arduino, just manually connect them with a cable). One of the motors should turn one side.

Now connect in1 to 5V and in2 to GND (keeping enA connected to 5V), the motor should turn to the other side.

If this does not happen then you are not properly connecting the L298 or it is damaged.

If it works then the problem comes from your arduino. Connect 3 LEDs, one in the pin9, one in the pin 8 and one in the pin 10 (which are the pins you connect to in1 and in2 and enA).

Run your program and you should see the LEDS turn on and off accordingly.
If not, your arduino has a problem in some pins (maybe you short circuited them?)

If both experiments work there is absolutely no reason for them to not work together, so start small, divide your problem into pieces and identify it.

Good luck.